# Cannot link my domain with my website with IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, ip

I have a domain we will call rapport.website.fr and it redirects to the IP of my router (starting with 109.27.247) with the port 44306.
I created a website with Visual Studio and ASP.NET Core and published it by "Folder", using this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZG-6z4BQmRI. Then I used IIS to link it to the domain. But It only works on my computer while I would like to access the site from outside. I think that it is a problem of IP, but I don't know how to solve it.
On IIS, the site is linked to the port 80 and the port 44306 from every IP, on my "Hosts" file there is a line with the IP of my computer and the domain, and in the configuration of the website, there is :

```
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="109.27.247:44306:rapport.website.fr" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44306:rapport.website.fr" />
```

and some others. I also added a NAT with my computer IP and the port 44306 (external and destination).
I didn't find any complete tutorial that works and I'm lost in the different IP, can someone help me please ?

Comment: "it redirects to the IP of my router (starting with 109.27.247) with the port 44306" does not sound right. Why do you want to use port 44306? Does your ISP block port 80 and 443?

Comment: 44306 is the port that was used with localhost to test the website from VisualStudio so I thought that I had to use it. When I try to make a NAT with the port 80 (80 to 44306)  I can't access anymore to the parameters of the router

Comment: Not sure what kind of router you use, but if you want to make HTTPS work in that case, you should let your router monitor external traffic (from the internet) at port 443 (IP 109.27.247.xxx), and then forward the incoming requests to your IIS machine at port 44306 (internal IP xx.xx.xx.xx, and if you like to keep using that port). Then if you are lucky `https://rapport.website.fr` might work. This is purely a question on network setup, so not in scope of Stack Overflow.